# Updating table cells until reaching a predefined total

Tags: sql, cells, updating

I'm trying to solve a question via SQL ...

Let's suppose this is my table:

```
NAME | ITEM1 | ITEM2 | ITEM3                                                  
 AAA    1       2       1   
 BBB    2       1       3 
 CCC        3       2       1
 DDD        3       1       2
 EEE        1       3       1
```

Now, 1 and 2 are the values I have to keep stored in. The 3 value is the one I have to modify in every column ...now, this value must be changed to 1 until reaching a defined total, else it must be changed to 2.

For example : in the ITEM1 column, let's suppose I need to have three times the value 1. It means I should modify one of the two 3 present values with 1 (It doesn't matter which) and the other one with 2. And so on for all the remaining columns ...

Could you please help me finding a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this will work for your case, but it does what you want. The problem is size of the query (2 updates for each column).
obs. #teste is your table

```
declare @max_number_1_per_column int = 3
declare @coun_1 int
--assuming that you need to update all columns with the same rule (max number 1 in each column is 3, in this example)
--assuming name is unique

select @coun_1 = count(*) from #teste where item1 = 1

if (@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1 > 0)
    update      #teste
    set         item1 = 1   
    where       name in (select top(@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1) name from #teste where item1 = 3)


update      #teste
set         item1 = 2
where       item1 = 3


---other column
select @coun_1 = count(*) from #teste where item2 = 1

if (@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1 > 0)
    update      #teste
    set         item2 = 1   
    where       name in (select top(@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1) name from #teste where item2 = 3)


update      #teste
set         item2 = 2
where       item2 = 3



---other column
select @coun_1 = count(*) from #teste where item3 = 1

if (@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1 > 0)
    update      #teste
    set         item3 = 1   
    where       name in (select top(@max_number_1_per_column - @coun_1) name from #teste where item3 = 3)


update      #teste
set         item3 = 2
where       item3 = 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I’ll test it tomorrow morning ! Keep you updated. Thanks !

Comment: Well ... THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!! this is really what i need. I just add a "order by NEWID()"  at the end of the first update to randomize the operation ... it works GREAT ! Thank you so much, i owe you a beer !!!